# join 2 tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I’m new to Laravel5 and even if I’ve made some progress with my site, I’m stuck in something that may be simple for you.
I have 2 tables: Users and Books

Users:

```
UserID|FirstName|LastName
1|John|Doe
2|Mark|Lehman
3|Dan|Edward
```

Books: (it means that the user with the ID of UserID has read the book with the ID of BookID

```
BookID|UserID
1|1
1|2
```

I want to find first name and last name of all the users who read the book with the id of 1 (I’m passing this id to a function, finduser($id))
In the above example finduser(1) should return:
John Doe
Mark Lehman

(i think in php is something like: select (FirstName, LastName) from Users join Books on (Users.ID=Books.userID).

I created the function finduser($id) in helpers.php not in a controller. I call this function into a view. I'm also interested in how i call the returns of this function into the view an how I echo them out...

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You're question has some scope creep on the tail. address the 'to view' in another question. include code snippets of what you've tried, in this case at least the finduser function. also post what error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I can't address the "view" question in anothe rtopic because i created the finduser function to echo something in the view...     here's something i've done:

```
     function finduser($id){
return $users=DB::table(users)
    ->select('users.FirstName',’users.LastName’)
    ->join(Books, Books.UserID','=',user.ID')
    ->where(Books.ID','=',$id)
    ->get();
}
```

in the view:

```
@if(finduser(targetID)!=null)
    $us=finduser(targetID);
    @foreach($us as $u)
        {{$u}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

the result:
$us=visitors($item->ID);
...which is pretty stupid...`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Create a relationship http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

In your User model

```
public function books() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
}
```

In your Book model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then when you want to find the user that owns the book, just call your book by:

```
$book = Book::find(1); // find the book with id 1
$book->user // This gives you the user that owns that book. Try dd($book->user);
```